# Improve pagespeed score when there is a vimeo on the first screen

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pagespeed, lighthouse

I have a website in NextJS 13 which is pretty fast
I have a video on the first screen using vimeo embedded

I'm trying to do several way in other to avoid vimeo iframe affect the page speed.
I've done something like check if [effectiveType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/effectiveType) is 4G (or higher). Only load the video on [requestIdleCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback)

```
if (
  // skip video if internet connection is slower than 4G
  ['slow-2g', '2g', '3g'].includes(
    navigator?.connection?.effectiveType ?? '4g'
  ) ||
  // check effective bandwidth in Mbps. Pagespeed for mobile now is using Slow 4G at 1,638.4 kb/s
  (navigator?.connection?.downlink ?? 10) < 10
) {
  // do not embed the video
}
```

The thing is, with those improvements, I got 95 ~ 98 on the lighthouse, but only ~60 on page speed insight because of the bad Total Blocking Time.

Do you have any suggestions to help me here?
I'm thinking about disabling video on a slow internet connection by checking the [downlink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/downlink) but it hasn't worked so far.

Note: I'm allowed to use the latest technologies, and I'm also allowed to disable vimeo in some specific cases in order to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few open source [Vimeo facade](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/third-party-facades#vimeo_embedded_player) libraries that will defer all of the expensive 3P resources/execution until the user interacts with the video. It will still look like the embedded video on load, but none of the actual functionality will work until needed.

Comment: Thank you Rick, I checked this link before posting the question. Unfortunately, none of them works for me. And I do want the video autoplay, not only when users interact with the video.